# How to pass large number of parameters from Angular js to rest service

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

I am trying to fetch parameters from angular JS **`$http`** service to rest service using **`@queryParam**` . I need to fetch lot of parameters(below have shown for 3 as an example ,but I need to use around 12-15 of them which I need to pass to the java side) ,so fetching all with @QueryParam makes the code look pretty bad .I am using `GET`.

How can I optimize this ?

Example what I am doing -

Angular Js code -

```
$http({
    url: someUrl, 
    method: "GET",
    params: {filter1: $scope.filter1,
filter2:$scope.filter2,
filter3:$scope.filter3
 });
```

Java side -

```
@path("/getAllData")
@GET
@Produces({..}
public response getAllData(@QueryParam("filter1") final String filter1,
                           @QueryParam("filter2") final String filter2,
                           @QueryParam("filter3") final String filter3){
}
```

Also ,wanted to know the optimization in case when I am building URL instead of params object, and picking the same with `@PathParam`

```
$http.get('rest/test/getAllData/?filter1='$scope.filter1 + 
           '&filter2='$scope.filter2 + '&filter3='$scope.filter3 + 
           '&filter4='$scope.filter4)
```

I am able to do it by passing individually in @QueryParam . I am looking for optimized code when we a large number of parameters.

Comment: Possible duplicates [how to pass java object as a parameter in restful webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17038000/how-to-pass-java-object-as-a-parameter-in-restful-webservice)

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO with all the required parameters.

In angular, do this

```
var obj = {};
obj.filter1 =  $scope.filter1;
obj.filter2 =  $scope.filter2;
obj.filter3 =  $scope.filter3;


$http({
    url: someUrl, 
    method: "GET",
    params: obj
});
```

You can accept all the parameters in you rest like this -

```
@path("/getAllData")
@GET
@Produces({..}
public response getAllData(MyPojo obj){
  //String filter1 = obj.filter1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 ways:

1) `org.json.simple.JSONObject`.

2) Bean or POJO Class.

**AngularJS Controller:**

```
var URL = appURL+'/adm/addCollProcess.do';
var json = {"col_pro_id":$scope.col_pro_id, "col_code": $scope.col_code, "exam_type_ids": $scope.exam_types.toString().replace("[","").replace("]",""), 
    "created_by" : "admin", "file_path" : $scope.file_path, "website" : $scope.website, "facebook" : $scope.facebook};

// using JSONObject
$http.post(URL, json).then(function(response){
    if(response.data){
       // Code
    }
});

// using Bean Class
 $http.post(URL, JSON.stringify(json)).then(function(response){
    if(response.data){
       // Code
    }
});
```

**Java Controller:**

```
// using JSONObject
@RequestMapping(value="/addCollProcess.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean addCollProcess(@RequestBody JSONObject json){
    // Code
}

// using Bean Class:
@RequestMapping(value="/addCollProcess.do", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody boolean addCollProcess(@RequestBody AdmissionProcessBean processBean) {
    // Code
}
```