# JAX-RS 2 and Jersey 2 : how to pass an (hash)map on a GET request

Tags: get, hashmap, jax-ws, jax-rs

I simply want to pass an map to my @GET method on my web services using JAX-RS 2. I want to know if it's possible and how to make it, even if GET's methods don't have any body.

Like this :

```
@GET
@Path(??)
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public User find(@PathParam(??) HashMap<String, String> map) {
    // work on map !
}
```

I've seen that it existed the MultiValued map but it's for the parameters. How to pass an map please ?

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have Jackson jars in your classpath (or any other XML / JSON to Map mapper)
You probably don't want to pass the map on the `@PathParam`, for aesthetical, convention and security reasons. You usually pass a JSON / XML object as the request body, e.g. using a POST / PUT

```
@POST
@Path("/anypath")
@Consumes({"text/xml", "application/json"})
public User find(HashMap<String, String> map) {
    //magic should happen
}
```

Then just pass a POST / PUT request with content type application/json or text/xml that has 
e.g.

```
{
  "key1": "value1"
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

If you have the right Jackson / Moxy etc mapper in the classpath, it will do the conversion between the JSON / XML format to a `java.util.Map` (or even a POJO) for you

The `@Produces` is only needed if you intend to also return XML / JSON, but since you are expecting either XML or JSON, then having a `@Consumes` makes sense here.

However, if you must pass the JSON object on a GET request, e.g. as a request param, take a look at this question: [Convert JSON query parameters to objects with JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697541/convert-json-query-parameters-to-objects-with-jax-rs)

p.s. for xml the mime is `text/xml` and not `application/xml`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is for a search feature and my boss wants exclusively a GET request... So I was constraint to use a url list (yes this is not pretty...) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get comfortable with @Context.

```
@GET
public Response superSpecialSearch(@Context UriInfo info, @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    var iAmAMutivalueMap = info.getQueryParameters(true);
    var searchResults = searchForThings( iAmAMultivalueMap ); 
    return Response.ok(searchResults )
}
```