# Jersey | List<Object> into client post/get/put request?

Tags: java, http, parameters, jersey, jax-rs

Is it possible to pass a list of Integers into a HttpPost/HttpGet/HttpPut etc, and have it passed into the resource?

```
public <ReturnType> methodName(@<Jersey annotation> List<Object> objects)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```java
@GET
@Path("/resource")
public Response restMethod(@QueryParam("num") List<Integer> ints)
```

Which can then be called like:

```
http://localhost/resource?num=1&num=2&num=3
```

Comment: This does not apply to wrapper classes though, can it?

(i.e. List<WrapperClass> instead of List<Integer>)

Comment: By wrapper class do you mean non-primitive type?

Comment: Yea like my own POJO pretty much

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697541/convert-json-query-parameters-to-objects-with-jax-rs and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061292/how-can-i-pass-complex-objects-as-arguments-to-a-restful-service