# How can I pass a complex object to @GET method and return another object ? Or is there a better way for doing this?

Tags: java, json, web-services, http-get, getmethod

I am writing a rest service which takes a list of complex Java objects (passed as a JSON object) as a parameter , and returns a java object (in JSON fomat). For instance, the get method takes in a list of A objects and returns B object. How can I do this with @GET method?  Or is there a better way for doing this?

```
@Path("get/")
@GET
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public B getData(List<A> listOfObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Path("get/{query}")
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public B getData(@QueryParam("query") String query);
```

and manually parse your list in method body with your favorite json parser

or as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697541/convert-json-query-parameters-to-objects-with-jax-rs) - you can make some custom wrapper